# mysql_insert_id() not working

Tags: php

```
<?php

$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$price = $ad['price'];
$owner = $ad['owner']; //owner of advertisement

//make a bid for this advertisement
$query = "INSERT INTO bids (id, ad, bidder, bid, bidwhen, owner, quantity)
         VALUES (NULL, '$adid', '$userid','$price', now(), '$owner', 1)";
$bidData = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$message = $_POST['message']; //message to owner

if ($message != "") { //if message box is not empty insert comment
    $title = $ad['title'];
    $bidid = mysql_insert_id($bidData); //Line 123 get last id of bid insert and put it into message query for reference

    $query = "INSERT INTO messages (sentto, sentfrom, sentat, message, title, bid)
    VALUES ('$owner', '$userid', now(), '$message', '$title', '$bidid')";
    $messageData = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
}

?>
```

Error message:

```
mysql_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

When i dont pass a parameter i get this error message:

```
Warning: mysql_insert_id() [function.mysql-insert-id]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\projects\xampp\htdocs\phpprojects\lets\ad.php on line 123

Warning: mysql_insert_id() [function.mysql-insert-id]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\projects\xampp\htdocs\phpprojects\lets\ad.php on line 123
```

**Solution Code:**

```
<?php

$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$price = $ad['price'];
$owner = $ad['owner']; //owner of advertisement

mysqli_close($dbc);
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (!$dbc) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($dbc, 'databasename');

//make a bid for this advertisement
$query = "INSERT INTO bids (id, ad, bidder, bid, bidwhen, owner, quantity)
         VALUES (NULL, '$adid', '$userid','$price', now(), '$owner', 1)";
$bidData = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$message = $_POST['message']; //message to owner

if ($message != "") { //if message box is not empty insert comment
    $title = $ad['title'];
    $bidid = mysql_insert_id($dbc); //get last id of bid insert and put it into message query for reference

    $query = "INSERT INTO messages (sentto, sentfrom, sentat, message, title, bid)
    VALUES ('$owner', '$userid', now(), '$message', '$title', '$bidid')";
    $messageData = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The argument passed to `mysql_insert_id` is the resource of a database connection. You're feeding it the result of a MySQL query. Just `mysql_insert_id()` by itself *should* work unless you're opening multiple database connections.

https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id

Answer (score 7):

1. What pygorex1 said.  You don't want to pass the result of a query to *insert_id()
2. Why are you using mysql**i**_query(), but mysql_insert_id()?  If you're using mysqli, use [myqli_insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: my problem was using mysql_insert_id() instead of mysqli_insert_id($conn)

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the result of `mysqli_query`, you should be doing it like:

```
if (($bidData = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) !== true) {
       printf("Error: %s in query %s\n", $mysqli->error,$query);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of late, but I see in php manual, the interface are below:

1. `int mysql_insert_id ([ resource $link_identifier ] );`
2. `int mysqli_insert_id ( mysqli $link )`.

So, I think:

1. You have to use `mysqli_insert_id($link)` if you are mysqli style;
2. You should always pass the link identifier to `mysqli_insert_id` function.